# posts_per_page => 1 shows 2 posts

Tags: query-posts

I am trying to add a button to take the viewer to a random post. Below's the code I am using:-

```
    <?php query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 1));
    if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-lot">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Yes, Robo! Take me there.</a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
```

But, it keeps showing two links. If I change `posts_per_page` to 2, it shows 3 links. I tried adding `wp_reset_query` but the issue still persists.

Comment: Where is this code running? The context may provide more clues, especially if you can paste the code wrapped around it. :)

Comment: Never use `query_posts()` until you are 100% sure you have to do so. Use `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` instead. [See the Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#more-information).

Comment: @WebElaine Its running on the 404 page.

Comment: @MaxYudin I also tried using `WP_Query` as seen here - https://www.wpexplorer.com/random-posts-wordpress/ but the result's the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably you have a sticky post there. If you want exact number of posts you need to ignore sticky posts. So your query should look like this:

```
query_posts( array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
) );
```

or as suggested, never use `query_posts()`

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
) );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for that, this fixed the issue and as suggested, I will implement `WP_Query`.